# UFW not blocking traffic at ubuntu server vm's

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, firewall, ufw

I have an Ubuntu server 16.04 host, with KVM running Ubuntu server 16.04 guests, the guests are bridged to a NIC (lets name it ens1) that is connected to the internet and in addition they are all connected to a private network via another NIC (lets name it ens2) that is isolated from the outer web.

I wish to block all traffic at ens2 except specific ports and allow all traffic at ens1, yet I have encountered basic problems:

At guest1 I did:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw enable
```

Afterwards I could not ping from guest1 to guest2 yet at guest2 I could still ping to guest1. what am I missing?

This is the result of `sudo ufw status verbose`:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK seems that for some reason the ufw let me ping my machine yet all other operations are blocked so it works just not as one might think it would.